# How do I convert an ArrayList of string arrays to a 2D string array?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have a function which processes an `ArrayList` of `String` arrays and is supposed to return a two-dimensional array of strings:

```
public String[][] myFunction() {
    ArrayList<String[]> myArrayList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    ...
    return myArrayList.toArray(String[][]);
}
```

Which does not work. Casting to type `String[][]` also does not work:

```
return (String[][]) myArrayList.toArray();
```

Note that I need `String[][]`, **not** `Object[][]`.

How do I get this to work?

Comment: how is java supposed to know how you want your 2d array created from a 1d array? how big is it supposed to be? Are all rows the same, does it put a single element per row per size of the 1d array? There are infinite number of ways to create the 2d array from the 1d array. Give us an example of what the 2d array should like given a 1d array.

Comment: Yes all rows are the same. Maximum 16 rows and sqrt(16) elements per row.

Comment: `return myArrayList.toArray(String[][]);` -> `return myArrayList.toArray(String[][]::new);`

Comment: @saka1029 this gives error `String[][] is not a functional interface` at compile time.

Comment: myArrayList.toArray(new String[][]{});

Comment: make it like this `return myArrayList.toArray(new String[][]{});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `toArray` method of the `List` interface

```
ArrayList<String[]> myArrayList = new ArrayList<String[]>();

myArrayList.add(new String[] {"A","B","C"});
myArrayList.add(new String[] {"AA","BB","CC"});

String[][] array = myArrayList.toArray(String[][]::new);
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array));
```

Prints

```
[[A, B, C], [AA, BB, CC]]
```

Here are two other approaches.  In both cases, they will work fine with different length arrays.

This one simply copies the array that is in the list.  So if you alter the contents of any array in the list, the array of arrays will also be altered.

```
String[][] array = new String[myArrayList.size()][];
for (int i = 0; i < myArrayList.size(); i++) {
    array[i] = myArrayList.get(i);
}
```

This simply makes a copy of the existing array in the list to avoid the problem described previously.

```
String[][] array = new String[myArrayList.size()][];
for (int i = 0; i < myArrayList.size(); i++) {
    String[] arr = myArrayList.get(i);
    array[i] = Arrays.copyOf(arr, arr.length);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
static String[][] listTo2dArray(ArrayList<String[]> arlS) {
    String[][] arr2D = new String[arlS.size()][arlS.get(0).length];
    for(int i =0;i<arlS.size();i++) {
        arr2D[i] = arlS.get(i);
    }
    return arr2D;
}
```

Assuming you list have same number of elements for every row